# Java else part is not getting executed

Tags: java

I am having a piece of if-else code to check if a string is displayed, to my surprise the Else part is not getting executed at all.

For eg: If the error string is shown, the IF part works fine. In cases where the error string is not shown, the Else part is not getting executed. Kindly help

```
if(getErrText.length() > 0) {
    System.out.println(getErrText + " For "+ readerIterator);
} else {
    System.out.println(" Error is not displayed - Err Cell" + " For "+ readerIterator);
}
```

Comment: Check what gets returned when you call `getErrText.length()`. Make sure to trim the `getErrText` string if necessary.

Comment: Just add System.out.println("'" + getErrText + "'" ); before the if-statement and see what is inside of it when you think the else part should be executed.

Comment: Does the program continue executing when the "else" part is not executed? Or does the program throw an exception when the "else" part is not executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I make a few assumptions,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String getErrText = ""; // <--------------- To trigger else.
  String readerIterator = "Yes it is"; // <-- To display a message.
  if (getErrText.length() > 0) { // <-------- else means that getErrText **must** be ""
    System.out.println(getErrText + " For "
        + readerIterator);
  } else {
    System.out.println("Error is not displayed "
        + "- Err Cell For " + readerIterator);
  }
}
```

Output is

```
Error is not displayed - Err Cell For Yes it is
```

As I would expect.

**Edit**

As per comment(s), your actual problem is likely to be one of

```
// trim() the String!
if (getErrText != null && getErrText.trim().length() > 0) {
  // as before...
}
```

or silently swallowing your exception. **Please** don't do that.

```
try { 
  getErrText = toSearch.errorCell.getText();
  getErrText = (getErrText != null) ? getErrText.trim() : "";
}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: Thankyou It worked cool ! I did an Exception catch and designed as you suggested. cool !

Answer (score 0):

You are probably enclosing this within a block where error is set which is why your getErrText length is always greater than zero.

Could you please add your enclosing code for getting the error text please

1. In case you else is not getting executed, print the if part of your code and debug.
2. If both your if and else dont get executed, then the flow is not reaching your if-else at all for those scenarios .

Comment: try{
             
             getErrText = toSearch.errorCell.getText();
             
            }catch(Exception E){
             
            }

Comment: Change your if to System.out.println(":"+getErrText + ": For "+ readerIterator) and see what it prints when you are expecting it to be of zero length

Answer (score 0):

To find out your problem, print the error on your else:

```
System.out.println(" Error is not displayed - Err Cell" + " For "+ readerIterator+" The getErrText is ["+getErrText+"]);
```

Comment: It would be empty there. Look at the if test.

Comment: Empty has length 0. If it was anything but empty the getErrText would be shown.

Comment: And the if block would be entered (not the else).

Comment: You are saying that the length HAS to be zero. Makes sense.